# How to skip a for cycle interaction without interrupting the entire cycle - C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Hi I would like to know how I can skip to the next iteration of a for cycle under a certain condition if .
I am making :

```
for(int i=0; i<iteration ; i++){
if ( ...)
break;
}
```

but in this way the entire cylce finishes and does not go to the next iteration.

Comment: Use `continue` and a C++ beginner's book, which this website cannot replace ^^

Comment: You are looking for `continue`.

Comment: You could also negate the condition and put your code inside the conditional. Sometimes this is more readable than `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

use the `continue` statement. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue).

```
for(int i=0; i<iteration ; i++){
if ( ...) {
continue; }
}
```

Comment: thanks I was writing the answer when you posted yours!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<iteration ; i++){
if ( ...) { continue; } ;
else ...
}
```

everything after

```
continue
```

is skipped and the cycle goes directly to the next iteraction.